# ngrx state preservance in redirecting

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My requirement is to rediect a third party url from my angular app once the customer
complete the activities from third party app they will redirect back to my angular app.

I am using ngrx for state management. But the problem is when the third party app redirects back
to my application I cannot able to preserve the state from ngrx store.

Ngrx state is not preserved.

Due to security reasons we are not using localstorage and session storage.

Is this functionality achieved by ngrx itself or  I need to use either of localstorage or session storage.

How to solve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ngrx state management relies on memory which is preserved whilst the app is served. If you redirect into the application this will trigger an initiation load. Memory will be lost and your store will be reset, there is no two ways about it. You either have to use browser storage or a request to a server to fetch fresh data.